# .logarchive showing as a folder, not as a bundle

Tags: ios, macos

On some of my Macs, .logarchive files are showing as folders instead of bundles. I need them as file bundles in order to open them in Console.app. Cannot figure out what's configured differently in these Macs, but I'd like to be able to flip them back into bundles. By the way, these are sysdiagnose files coming from iOS devices. Does anyone know what to do?